# react-rails: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I'm using the [react-rails gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails).

Ive written a component `SortableTable` that I am trying to extend:

In `components/common/sortable_table.jsx`

```
class SortableTable extends React.Component
{
..
}
```

It works fine in `components/staff_dashboard/staff_dashboard_table.jsx`

```
class StaffDashboardTable extends SortableTable {
...
}
```

but in `components/accounting_team_dashboard/accounting_team_dashboard_table.jsx`

```
class AccountingTeamTable extends SortableTable {
...
}
```

I get the error `SortableTable is not defined`.

I read something about exporting the components so I added it:

```
class SortableTable extends React.Component
{
..
}
export default SortableTable
```

But this now gives an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`.

This on gem version **2.2.1**, **I'm not using web packer**. It's really odd to me that it works for the staff table - Maybe because it gets included below `SortableTable`?

Answer (score 1):

If extending the `SortableTable` component works in `components/staff_dashboard/staff_dashboard_table.jsx`

it will work in

`components/accounting_team_dashboard/accounting_team_dashboard_table.jsx` also

Now the problem could be that you are importing it from the wrong path.

You should import it like

In `components/staff_dashboard/staff_dashboard_table.jsx`

```
import SortableTable from '../common/sortable_table'
class StaffDashboardTable extends SortableTable {
...
}
```

and In `components/accounting_team_dashboard/accounting_team_dashboard_table.jsx`

```
import SortableTable from '../common/sortable_table'
class AccountingTeamTable extends SortableTable {
...
}
```

Comment: using `import` gives me a `require is not defined` error.